# If statement in my switch program doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement

This program is supposed to show a dropdown selection for the user, with an output of a response from that particular choice using switch statement in php. I can't get my if statement to work though. Can someone help me please? Thank you all.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Program 2</title>
</head>
<body>



<form action="<?php $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post">

<select name="pick">
<option value="regular">I am a regular customer</option>
<option value="friend">From a friend</option>
<option value="television">On television</option>
<option value="online">In an online search</option>

</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>


<?php  

    $choice = $_POST['pick'];

    if($choice($_POST['pick']) echo "Excellent. We love our regular     customers!";) {
} else {
switch($choice) {
    case 'regular':
         echo "Excellent. We love our regular customers!";
         break;
    case 'friend':
         echo "Please thank your friend for us.";
         break;
    case 'television':
         echo "We are glad to hear our TV ads are working.";
         break;
     case 'online':
         echo "We work hard to be found on Google.";
         break;
    }
   }
?>
```

Comment: or just use.,,jquery if you're simple echo a string based off a select value

Comment: I suggest you to check an actual php tutorial to avoid common mistake (here, I see `$PHP_SELF`, invalid uses of parenthesis with `$choice($_POST['pick'])`. If this is an exercice given by some teacher and the instruction is not "make this code valid", please tell him to update its courses.

Answer (score 2):

You've got lots of random copy/paste errors in your code... Instead use:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Program 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <select name="pick">
                <option value="regular">I am a regular customer</option>
                <option value="friend">From a friend</option>
                <option value="television">On television</option>
                <option value="online">In an online search</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
        </form>


        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['pick'])) {
                switch($_POST['pick']) {
                    case 'regular':
                         echo "Excellent. We love our regular customers!";
                         break;
                    case 'friend':
                         echo "Please thank your friend for us.";
                         break;
                    case 'television':
                         echo "We are glad to hear our TV ads are working.";
                         break;
                     case 'online':
                         echo "We work hard to be found on Google.";
                         break;
                }
           }
        ?>
    </body>
</htm
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for a if/else is the following:

```
if ($conditions)
{
  echo "conditions is true";
}
else
{
  echo "conditions is false";
}
```

your code is equivalent to:

```
if ($some_conditions)
  echo "condition is true";
// without braces, only the 1st instruction is concerned by the if 

{
echo "conditions is true";
}
else // syntax error here, because the "else" 
{
  echo "conditions is false";
}
```

When you're editing code, you can add this at the top of your scripts to have more information on errors:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "On");
?>
```